# How to force ubuntu touch to be in landscape on Nexus 7

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

I was wondering how I could force my Nexus 7 to run Ubuntu touch in landscape and have side-stages. 
Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately not a very helpful answer, but:

if you want to change it simply by doing some configuration edits it won't be possible. Quite a bit is yet hard coded and therefore it is clearly not yet the right time to start on this level.

Quite a bit of work has to be done till there is a universal configuration to change the individual behaviour like roation or side-stage.

I would say keep listening the different channels, like irc, mailinglist or the wiki and you will see when it will be possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this tutorial http://blog.wellsb.com/post/43774533626/side-stage-on-nexus-7-ubuntu-touch to enable side stage, but it's still in portrait.  I haven't had time to play around with forcing landscape, yet.